# runing on server a dynamic web project with google app engine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I’m trying to develop a dynamic web project and deploy it on google app engine.

After creating the project , I did run as ; `run on server` 
I got the following problem on the eclipse browser 
HTTP ERROR: 503

```
Problem accessing /. Reason: 
    SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE


Powered by Jetty:// 

package com.example.myproject;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MypfeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

Progress in Eclipse console :

```
avr. 08, 2015 1:39:32 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
AVERTISSEMENT: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
avr. 08, 2015 1:39:34 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFOS: Successfully processed C:\Utilisateurs\azza\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\Mypfe\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
avr. 08, 2015 1:39:34 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFOS: Successfully processed C:\Utilisateurs\azza\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\Mypfe\WEB-INF/web.xml
avr. 08, 2015 1:39:34 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFOS: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'D:\prog.util\eclipse\eclipse\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.18\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Utilisateurs\azza\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\Mypfe\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
avr. 08, 2015 1:39:35 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFOS: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
avr. 08, 2015 1:39:36 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFOS: jetty-6.1.x
avr. 08, 2015 1:39:39 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
AVERTISSEMENT: EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:216)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:288)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)

avr. 08, 2015 1:39:39 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
GRAVE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:288)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)

avr. 08, 2015 1:39:39 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
AVERTISSEMENT: failed Faces Servlet: java.lang.NullPointerException
avr. 08, 2015 1:39:39 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
AVERTISSEMENT: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@b19476{/,C:\Utilisateurs\azza\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\Mypfe}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:288)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)

avr. 08, 2015 1:39:40 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFOS: Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8888
avr. 08, 2015 1:39:40 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService startHotDeployScanner
INFOS: Full scan of the web app in place every 5s.
avr. 08, 2015 1:39:40 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFOS: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8888/
avr. 08, 2015 1:39:40 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFOS: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
avr. 08, 2015 1:39:40 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFOS: Dev App Server is now running
```

Comment: Without seing your code it is impossible to say something.

Comment: package com.example.myproject;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MypfeServlet extends HttpServlet {
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
   throws IOException {
  resp.setContentType("text/plain");
  resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
 }
}

Comment: please put it into original question